# WorksheetFeed with spreadSheetUrl doesn't work at all with GCP

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-drive-api, google-sheets-api

I'm using this little piece of code on my GoogleCloudPlateform website :

```
String key = fileId;
URL spreadSheetUrl = urlFactory.getWorksheetFeedUrl(key, "private", "full");
WorksheetFeed feed = service.getFeed(spreadSheetUrl,
WorksheetFeed.class);

WorksheetEntry ws = feed.getEntries().get(0);
```

But it seems that with the Drive API's update the code don't work at all.

When i'm doing this "service.getFeed(spreadSheetUrl,
WorksheetFeed.class);"  there is a new error until the 1st september :

```
com.qiis.radiall.crm.server.request.io.RequestExportToSpreadsheetTaskServlet doPost: Process failed (RequestExportToSpreadsheetTaskServlet.java:211)
com.google.gdata.util.RedirectRequiredException: FOUND

<HTML>
<HEAD>
<TITLE>Moved Temporarily</TITLE>
</HEAD>
<BODY BGCOLOR="#FFFFFF" TEXT="#000000">
<H1>Moved Temporarily</H1>
The document has moved <A HREF="https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JrAu-_XXX/edit">here</A>.
</BODY>
</HTML>
```

What i have to change ?

Any help would be appreciated
Thanks

Comment: Can you provide documentation reference to the methods used in the samples you provided? Most probably this is related to Sheets API v3 being shut down. Take a look at the corresponding [migration guide to v4](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/guides/migration).

Comment: Else, this might also not be an "error" and maybe something like a 302 redirect response since you have some sort of new  url to this file. Here it just seems your system is not using some follow redirect function. Can you check the http response type and try to enable some follow redirect?